# parser.js not found on Google CDN for dojo 1.10.3

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, cdn, google-cdn

I am using Google CDN in order to get DOJO.

This the code I am using in my website.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

When calling in my code module 'dojo/parser' like this

```
define([
    'dojo/topic',
    'dojo/parser',
    'dijit/registry'
], function (topic, parser) {
    var instance;

    function Test() {
    }
    Test.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            }.bind(this));
        }
    };
    return function getInstance() {
        return (instance = (instance || new Test()));
    };
});
```

I get 404 not found for module `parser`.
It actually point to Google CDN at address:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/dojo.js/parser.js

- Why module is missing on CDN? Or Am I missing something in my code?
- Any idea from where or how to load it?

Notes: If I am manually change the address to

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/parser.js
```

I get the file, could be a bug?

Comment: I'm having no problems with that URL. Do you have any custom packages configured in `dojoConfig`? Here's a working example with the same URL you're using: http://plnkr.co/edit/xgEi6qAPqKSNrUaoOQch?p=preview

Comment: I have the same problem, have you tried to define a module loading explicitly the parse module?

Comment: you are right a find the problem in custom packages, please add it as answer I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not within the URL, but probably due to some custom packages configured using `dojoConfig`.

Here's an example (without additional configuration) that does work: http://plnkr.co/edit/xgEi6qAPqKSNrUaoOQch?p=preview

If you you have custom modules and you're using a CDN, you should probably follow the guidelines described in [this article](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/cdn/). For example:

```
<script>
    var dojoConfig = {
        async: true,
        packages: [{
            name: 'custom',
            location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '') + '/custom'
        }]
    };
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```